# Simple C Program Approximating The Constant e

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that approximates e (e=1+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+...) to a limiting factor epsilon. The program should continue adding terms until the current statement becomes less than epsilon, where epsilon is a small (floating-point) number entered by a user.

I can write the program that approximates e to the nth term yet I am having trouble doing it to where it stops once the most recent term is less than epsilon.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int i=1,l;
float e,p,epsilon;

printf("Enter the value of epsilon: ");
scanf("%f", &epsilon);

for(;;)
{
    p=1;
    for(l = 1; l < 1; l--)
    {
        p*=l;
        if (1/p<epsilon) {
            goto done;
        }
    }

    e+=1/p;
    i++;
}

done:
    printf("The value of e limited by epsilon is %f\n",e);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop never executes: `1 < 1` is never true. Don't use single letter variable names, especially not lowercase L.

Comment: Where is the factorial function call?

Comment: You can build N! from (N-1)!.  Your inner loop would then not be necessary.  You shouldn't need a label in this.

Comment: In the absence of a strong reason not to use `double`, use `double` for floating point values. "Because my teacher told me to use `float`" is not a strong reason until you've tried (and failed) to convince the teacher `double` is better.

Comment: what an odd construct, using an infinite loop and breaking out of it with a `goto`.  Why don't you put the condition of `1/p<epsilon` into the `for`'s end condition?  Why don't you break out with `last` (or is it `break`?  I forget....)?

Comment: Having a configurable epsilon is probably useless. IMO it would be better to just loop until adding the next term does not change the value (a situation you'll arrive at *very quickly*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
double eulersNumber(double epsilon)
{
    double e = 0;
    double factorial = 1;

    for (int i = 1; TRUE; i++) {
        double add = 1.0 / factorial;

        if (add < epsilon)
            break;

        e += add;
        factorial *= i;
    }

    return e;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for _help_, not for a _solution_.

Comment: @Jan true, but I say potato, you say potato.

Comment: I am just learning c on my own and it actually not bad to have a solution to look over. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Something on these lines should help you

```
double expo ( double x, double epsilon )
{
       double sum=0;
       unsigned i=0;
       double fact=0;
       double factorial=1;
       while ( 1 )
       {
             fact=1/factorial; 
             if ((fact-epsilon) < 0.000001) /* Comparing doubles. Am I safe here? */
                 break;

             sum+=fact;
             i++;
             factorial*=i;
       }
       return sum;
}
```

Comment: you do realize that you can just use `factorial = 1` then `factorial = i*factorial; fact = 1/factorial`?

Answer (score 1):

Go to can be [harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) and your use of it should be minimized. 
Your second loop will never execute, given that 1 is never less that 1. If you wanna break out of a loop like this, then a while construct is fine. Something along this lines:

```
while(1)
   Do stuff until you get what you want. A second loop here should do.
   break;
```

Using this should make your program work.

Comment: I strongly disagree that goto should 'never' be used, If used properly, it can be very safe and much easier than other control systems. It is a part of the C language for a reason. With that said, I do agree using a goto here is a bit overkill.

Comment: I agree, I think my use of the word never is a bit of an exaggeration. I will change my wording.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the variable `e`. Initialize the variable before entering the loop:

```
e = 1;
```

You also probably meant to use the variable `i` to initialize `l` in the inner `for` loop. Loop conditional also seems to be reversed. Use

```
for(l = i; l > 0; l--)
```

instead of

```
for(l = 1; l < 1; l--)
```

Comment: @soulrain, in the code you posted you declare `float e` and then go on accessing its uninitialized value by doing `e+=1/p;`.